# Compare work items between releases in VSTS doesn't work

Tags: azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I've setup our release definition in VSTS and when I go into a release there is a work items tab. When I first go into it it lists the work items that are in that release, but there is to get the work items associated with this release since a previous release.  However, which ever release I choose I always get `No release found with name '<Release Name>'.`
Am I missing something?  I've retained the releases indefinitely and they do exist.  Is this a bug in VSTS?

Update - Following @marina's answer here is a screen shot of my Work Items tab:
[image]

As you can see I've got 1 bug work item in the list.  This is the work item that was fixed in Release 212.  This is what is displayed before I click Compare.  On clicking Compare I get the error message "No release found with name 'Release 211 for build xxx Lite-CI-Nightly-refs_heads_develop_2017.11.7.2 develop'.". There is definitely a release 211 and it did have a work item associated with it.  I'm getting the same error with any of the releases.  Is there something I've missed with the release definition?

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new release definition? Post the detail steps here.

Comment: @starain-MSFT - interesting idea.  I'll give it a try when i get a chance, but I don't believe I've done anything clever with my current release definition.

Answer (score 0):

The compare work items in release can work correctly.

Please check **if your current release has work item related**.
In the release summary Tab, check if the release has linked with work item(s).

[image]

If the current release is not related with work item, when you compare with pervious release (work items associated with this release since previous release), it will show `No associated work items found`.

When you select an old release to compare, it actually show the work items from the old release (**not contain**) to current release.

Assume your current release is `Release-4`, and the linked work items with different releases as below:

```
Release        Related work items
___________________________________
Release-4           none
Release-3    workitem3, workitem4
Release-2        workitem2
Release-1          none
```

For the current `Release-4`, it default show item associated with this release since `Release-3` (current release and **not include `Release-3`**), so it will show No associated work items found.

And if you select item associated with this release since `Release-2`, it will show the work item linked in `Release-3` and `Release-4`. So it will show `workitem3` and `workitem4` after you clicking compare button.

Comment: I've had a look through all of our Releases and they are all associated with Work Items.

Answer (score 0):

I find that in VSTS, the work items tab of the release menu allows to compare the current release with any previous release and get a list of work items added since then. This works well as long as work items are linked to commits during development (good practice). So all good.

The problem is with the 'send email' command, when using this the compare is to the last release even if it was never deployed. there is no way i can find to select a specific release to compare with.

Comment: the "send email" is unfortunately not taking the selected versions to compare into account. Hope this gets adjusted in future versions...